# How do I make a Metal window full screen?

Tags: c++, macos, metal

I'm working with the demo from here https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/ I want the app to run in full screen, but it keeps coming up as a window every time.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the style mask to `NS::WindowStyleMaskFullScreen` when calling NS::Window::init from my app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method. This produces no errors and launches the app in a window.
- Setting the style mask to `NS::WindowStyleMaskClosable | NS::WindowStyleMaskTitled | NS::WindowStyleMaskFullScreen` when calling NS::Window::init from my app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method. This produces no errors and launches the app in a window.
- Adding a toggleFullscreen method to NS::Window in NSWindow.hpp this calls through to `toggleFullScreen:` on the actual AppKit NSWindow. I then tried calling this method from a menu item and from my app delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching after calling makeKeyAndOrderFront. This had the same result. No errors, but the app launches in a window. When I activate the menu item my code is called and when I check the window claims to respond to the selector I'm calling. "toggleFullScreen:".
- I've also tried calling toggleFullScreen with both a pointer to the window and with nullptr. Neither made a difference.
- I've tried similar changes with the unmodified tutorial 09 code and I'm getting the same results there as well. App opens and doesn't go to fullscreen neither on launch nor when I activate the menu option.
- I created a new Metal app in Xcode with XIB/Objective-C to compare against. I'll explain that below.

I can push my slightly modified code to a git repo if it will help, but I pretty much just took the last example from that and disabled the auto capture code so it doesn't keep opening the generated gputrace in xcode.

I'm trying to update a 20 year old app that was originally using Carbon and OpenGL, but this is just a POC for how it will work. I'm trying to avoid getting into Objective-C/C++ code and keep this usable from the command line or as an app bundle. This probably doesn't matter, but because of that I'm using VSCode, make, and clang++ to build the actual app.

EDIT:
As described above the desired behavior is that the window is created fullscreen. The specific problem or error is that it is opening in windowed mode not fullscreen. Note the window is being created with a style mask including NS::WindowStyleMaskFullScreen.
Here is the minimal required code.

```
#include <cassert>

#define NS_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTL_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTK_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CA_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <AppKit/AppKit.hpp>
#include <MetalKit/MetalKit.hpp>

#pragma region Declarations {

class Renderer
{
    public:
        Renderer( MTL::Device* pDevice );
        ~Renderer();
        void draw( MTK::View* pView );

    private:
        MTL::Device* _pDevice;
        MTL::CommandQueue* _pCommandQueue;
};

class MyMTKViewDelegate : public MTK::ViewDelegate
{
    public:
        MyMTKViewDelegate( MTL::Device* pDevice );
        virtual ~MyMTKViewDelegate() override;
        virtual void drawInMTKView( MTK::View* pView ) override;

    private:
        Renderer* _pRenderer;
};

class MyAppDelegate : public NS::ApplicationDelegate
{
    public:
        ~MyAppDelegate();

        NS::Menu* createMenuBar();

        virtual void applicationWillFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification ) override;
        virtual void applicationDidFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification ) override;
        virtual bool applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed( NS::Application* pSender ) override;

    private:
        NS::Window* _pWindow;
        MTK::View* _pMtkView;
        MTL::Device* _pDevice;
        MyMTKViewDelegate* _pViewDelegate = nullptr;
};

#pragma endregion Declarations }


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    NS::AutoreleasePool* pAutoreleasePool = NS::AutoreleasePool::alloc()->init();

    MyAppDelegate del;

    NS::Application* pSharedApplication = NS::Application::sharedApplication();
    pSharedApplication->setDelegate( &del );
    pSharedApplication->run();

    pAutoreleasePool->release();

    return 0;
}


#pragma mark - AppDelegate
#pragma region AppDelegate {

MyAppDelegate::~MyAppDelegate()
{
    _pMtkView->release();
    _pWindow->release();
    _pDevice->release();
    delete _pViewDelegate;
}

NS::Menu* MyAppDelegate::createMenuBar()
{
    // using NS::StringEncoding::UTF8StringEncoding;
    using NS::UTF8StringEncoding;

    NS::Menu* pMainMenu = NS::Menu::alloc()->init();
    NS::MenuItem* pAppMenuItem = NS::MenuItem::alloc()->init();
    NS::Menu* pAppMenu = NS::Menu::alloc()->init( NS::String::string( "Appname", UTF8StringEncoding ) );

    NS::String* appName = NS::RunningApplication::currentApplication()->localizedName();
    NS::String* quitItemName = NS::String::string( "Quit ", UTF8StringEncoding )->stringByAppendingString( appName );
    SEL quitCb = NS::MenuItem::registerActionCallback( "appQuit", [](void*,SEL,const NS::Object* pSender){
        auto pApp = NS::Application::sharedApplication();
        pApp->terminate( pSender );
    } );

    NS::MenuItem* pAppQuitItem = pAppMenu->addItem( quitItemName, quitCb, NS::String::string( "q", UTF8StringEncoding ) );
    pAppQuitItem->setKeyEquivalentModifierMask( NS::EventModifierFlagCommand );
    pAppMenuItem->setSubmenu( pAppMenu );

    NS::MenuItem* pWindowMenuItem = NS::MenuItem::alloc()->init();
    NS::Menu* pWindowMenu = NS::Menu::alloc()->init( NS::String::string( "Window", UTF8StringEncoding ) );

    SEL closeWindowCb = NS::MenuItem::registerActionCallback( "windowClose", [](void*, SEL, const NS::Object*){
        auto pApp = NS::Application::sharedApplication();
            pApp->windows()->object< NS::Window >(0)->close();
    } );
    NS::MenuItem* pCloseWindowItem = pWindowMenu->addItem( NS::String::string( "Close Window", UTF8StringEncoding ), closeWindowCb, NS::String::string( "w", UTF8StringEncoding ) );
    pCloseWindowItem->setKeyEquivalentModifierMask( NS::EventModifierFlagCommand );

    pWindowMenuItem->setSubmenu( pWindowMenu );

    pMainMenu->addItem( pAppMenuItem );
    pMainMenu->addItem( pWindowMenuItem );

    pAppMenuItem->release();
    pWindowMenuItem->release();
    pAppMenu->release();
    pWindowMenu->release();

    return pMainMenu->autorelease();
}

void MyAppDelegate::applicationWillFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification )
{
    NS::Menu* pMenu = createMenuBar();
    NS::Application* pApp = reinterpret_cast< NS::Application* >( pNotification->object() );
    pApp->setMainMenu( pMenu );
    pApp->setActivationPolicy( NS::ActivationPolicy::ActivationPolicyRegular );
}

void MyAppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification )
{
    CGRect frame = (CGRect){ {100.0, 100.0}, {512.0, 512.0} };

    _pWindow = NS::Window::alloc()->init(
        frame,
        NS::WindowStyleMaskClosable|NS::WindowStyleMaskTitled|NS::WindowStyleMaskFullScreen,
        NS::BackingStoreBuffered,
        false );

    _pDevice = MTL::CreateSystemDefaultDevice();
 
    _pMtkView = MTK::View::alloc()->init( frame, _pDevice );
    _pMtkView->setColorPixelFormat( MTL::PixelFormat::PixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB );
    _pMtkView->setClearColor( MTL::ClearColor::Make( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) );

    _pViewDelegate = new MyMTKViewDelegate( _pDevice );
    _pMtkView->setDelegate( _pViewDelegate ); 

    _pWindow->setContentView( _pMtkView );
    _pWindow->setTitle( NS::String::string( "00 - Window", NS::StringEncoding::UTF8StringEncoding ) );

    _pWindow->makeKeyAndOrderFront( nullptr );

    NS::Application* pApp = reinterpret_cast< NS::Application* >( pNotification->object() );
    pApp->activateIgnoringOtherApps( true );
}

bool MyAppDelegate::applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed( NS::Application* pSender )
{
    return true;
}

#pragma endregion AppDelegate }


#pragma mark - ViewDelegate
#pragma region ViewDelegate {

MyMTKViewDelegate::MyMTKViewDelegate( MTL::Device* pDevice )
: MTK::ViewDelegate()
, _pRenderer( new Renderer( pDevice ) )
{
}

MyMTKViewDelegate::~MyMTKViewDelegate()
{
    delete _pRenderer;
}

void MyMTKViewDelegate::drawInMTKView( MTK::View* pView )
{
    _pRenderer->draw( pView );
}

#pragma endregion ViewDelegate }


#pragma mark - Renderer
#pragma region Renderer {

Renderer::Renderer( MTL::Device* pDevice )
: _pDevice( pDevice->retain() )
{
    _pCommandQueue = _pDevice->newCommandQueue();
}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    _pCommandQueue->release();
    _pDevice->release();
}

void Renderer::draw( MTK::View* pView )
{
    NS::AutoreleasePool* pPool = NS::AutoreleasePool::alloc()->init();

    MTL::CommandBuffer* pCmd = _pCommandQueue->commandBuffer();
    MTL::RenderPassDescriptor* pRpd = pView->currentRenderPassDescriptor();
    MTL::RenderCommandEncoder* pEnc = pCmd->renderCommandEncoder( pRpd );
    pEnc->endEncoding();
    pCmd->presentDrawable( pView->currentDrawable() );
    pCmd->commit();

    pPool->release();
}

#pragma endregion Renderer }
```

EDIT2: The XIB file uses the same togglefullscreen: selector that I tried. It also defined some other params that I looked into.

```
<window title="Metal2" allowsToolTipsWhenApplicationIsInactive="NO" autorecalculatesKeyViewLoop="NO" releasedWhenClosed="NO" animationBehavior="default" id="QvC-M9-y7g">
  <windowStyleMask key="styleMask" titled="YES" closable="YES" resizable="YES"/>
  <windowCollectionBehavior key="collectionBehavior" fullScreenNone="YES"/>
  <windowPositionMask key="initialPositionMask" leftStrut="YES" rightStrut="YES" topStrut="YES" bottomStrut="YES"/>
```

I saw this was adding the resizeable style mask so I tried that and suddenly I could go fullscreen after the app had launched, but I still couldn't launch in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think it's currently impossible to launch in fullscreen. I could in the past with CGL and AGL, but those are deprecated and very flaky now. I have found a workaround that only hurts a little.
This involves editing the files downloaded as part of the metal-cpp package. We need to make [NSWindow toggleFullScreen:] available to our c++ code.

In metal-cpp-extensions/AppKit/AppKitPrivate.hpp Add these two lines towards the bottom. This creates a selector we can use later.

```
 _APPKIT_PRIVATE_DEF_SEL( windows,
                                                "windows" );
 
+_APPKIT_PRIVATE_DEF_SEL( toggleFullScreen_,
+                                               "toggleFullScreen:" );
 }
```

In metal-cpp-extensions/AppKit/NSWindow.hpp we need to create our toggleFullScreen method on our NS::Window class. Add the toggleFullScreen line between setTitle and close.

```
                        void                            setContentView( const View* pContentView );
                        void                            makeKeyAndOrderFront( const Object* pSender );
                        void                            setTitle( const String* pTitle );
+                       void                            toggleFullScreen( const Object* pSender );
 
                        void                            close();
```

Then further down near the implementation of NS::Window::close() I added this implementation of toggleFullScreen.

```
_NS_INLINE void NS::Window::toggleFullScreen( const Object* pSender )
{
       Object::sendMessage< void >( this, _APPKIT_PRIVATE_SEL( toggleFullScreen_ ), pSender );
}
```

To figure this out I copied what NS::Window::makeKeyAndOrderFront did.
All of that gets us our magical toggleFullScreen method which combined with the style mask of `NS::WindowStyleMaskClosable|NS::WindowStyleMaskTitled|NS::WindowStyleMaskResizable` lets us toggle in and out of fullscreen.

I was able to get the MenuItem to work by telling it to call toggleFullScreen: itself, but now I can have it call a callback fn where I can do anything I want before doing the toggle.

This still left me with no sane way to make the app "start" in fullscreen. I searched for a while and only found two other mentions of starting this way. Both of them were here on SO. They both did basically the same thing. Start the app normally and toggle into fullscreen asap after launching. So I started right after the call to `NS::Window::alloc()->init(...)` and moved it down line by line until it stopped crashing on launch. I currently have it as the very last line of applicationDidFinishLaunching.

Here is the full applicationDidFinishLaunching method with my changes. But remember you also need to make the changes to the hpp files to allow us to call toggleFullScreen.

```cpp
void MyAppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification )
{
    CGRect frame = (CGRect){ {100.0, 100.0}, {512.0, 512.0} };

    _pWindow = NS::Window::alloc()->init(
        frame,
        // Modified this line to replace NS::WindowStyleFullScreen with NS::WindowStyleMaskResizable 
        NS::WindowStyleMaskClosable|NS::WindowStyleMaskTitled|NS::WindowStyleMaskResizable,
        NS::BackingStoreBuffered,
        false );

    _pDevice = MTL::CreateSystemDefaultDevice();
 
    _pMtkView = MTK::View::alloc()->init( frame, _pDevice );
    _pMtkView->setColorPixelFormat( MTL::PixelFormat::PixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB );
    _pMtkView->setClearColor( MTL::ClearColor::Make( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ) );

    _pViewDelegate = new MyMTKViewDelegate( _pDevice );
    _pMtkView->setDelegate( _pViewDelegate ); 

    _pWindow->setContentView( _pMtkView );
    _pWindow->setTitle( NS::String::string( "00 - Window", NS::StringEncoding::UTF8StringEncoding ) );

    _pWindow->makeKeyAndOrderFront( nullptr );

    NS::Application* pApp = reinterpret_cast< NS::Application* >( pNotification->object() );
    pApp->activateIgnoringOtherApps( true );
    // Added this line
    _pWindow->toggleFullScreen(nullptr);
}
```

Overall I really like how the c++ to Objective-C bindings are setup. I wish they were available for more of the Apple APIs.